# How do I cast screen from Pixel 3 to something that is not Chromecast?

Tags: chromecast, screencast, miracast, google-pixel-3-xl

Booting Chromecast requires working Internet with unhindered connection to a Google server with a non-fake TLS certificate. So using Chromecast seems to be not an option in my use case.

What else can be used to cast screen / audio from Pixel 3 to some HDMI-outputting device? Are there alternative hardware devices that are compatible with Pixel 3? Can [rooted] Pixel 3 running Android 9 use Miracast instead with some third-party software?

Or maybe there are some other methods to make a "virtual Google" to allow Chromecast 3 to activate?

Comment: Wired or wireless? If wired can there be a PC-like object between the screen and phone or does it have to be seamless/user friendly?

Comment: Maybe wired, maybe wireless, but with lag comparable to using Chromecast/Miracast.

Maybe with some compact, cheap-ish and fanless device in between.

Comment: I was thinking of using [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) on [a Raspberry PI](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/179) might work for you. Not sure if [audio forwarding](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/14) works on RPi if you need it. You would have to see if the lag is acceptable.

Comment: @MorrisonChang, Is it substantially different from using `adb exec-out screenrecord --output-format=h264 -`-derived hacks?

Comment: `scrcpy` has its own server APK and uses bi-directional stream over adb. See: https://blog.rom1v.com/2018/03/introducing-scrcpy/ as the author addresses that exact case.